# How to get the percent sign using the latex moodle package

Tags: moodle, percent-sign

I'm preparing a quiz for moodle using the `moodle` package (+ LuaLaTeX).

When I input a percentage in the usual way (i.e. `40\,\%`), the LaTeX render is OK but the backslash is passed along to moodle and appears in the text:

[image]

As a workaround, I redefined `\%` to be `\char"0025` but this doesn't work since the moodle package just doesn't care.

I haven't found any relevant entry in the manual.

Any suggestion?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Révisions}
\begin{numerical}
Calculer 40\,\% de 120.
\item 48
\end{numerical}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

After adding

```
\makeatletter%
\html@action@def\%\g@addto@macro\htmlize@output{\otherpercent}}%
\makeatother
```

to the preamble as suggested by @mgk in the comments, the percent sign is now correctly rendered in the question text but the backslash remains present in any answer text.

[image: correct input is rejected]
[image: incorrect input is validated]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\makeatletter\html@action@def\%{\g@addto@macro\htmlize@output{\otherpercent}}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Révisions}
\begin{shortanswer}{Q1}
Enter the string \texttt{"40\%"}.
\item 40\%
\end{shortanswer}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's ping @mgk on this (he is doing wonderful work on https://gitlab.mattgk.myds.me/mattguer/moodle/)

Comment: @Rmano Who knows the callsigns rules the world!

Comment: Some symbol that has mysteriously gone under the radar until recently (fixed in the development version of the package). Would adding the following to the preamble help? `\makeatletter\html@action@def\%{\g@addto@macro\htmlize@output{\otherpercent}}\makeatother`

Comment: @mkg It partly works (no more backslashes in the question text) but the problem remains inside the correct answer to a shortanswer (for instance). I didn't include that part in the MWE, should have. I can't access your gitlab from my workplace, is there any other way to submit bug reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run into two problems with version `0.8` of the `moodle` package.

1. The macro `\%` is not declared for conversion to HTML.
2. The answers of `shortanswer` questions are passed as-is to the XML without going through conversion to HTML.

You can solve both by adding this code to the preamble, after loading `moodle`.

```latex
\makeatletter
\html@action@def\%{\g@addto@macro\htmlize@output{\otherpercent}}
\def\saveshortansweranswer@int@int#1\moodle@answer@rdelim{%
  \def\moodle@answertext{#1}%
  \trim@spaces@in\moodle@answertext
  \moodle@checkfraction
  \addto@xml[2]{\moodle@answers@xml}{<answer fraction="\moodle@fraction" 
   format="plain_text">}%
  \xa\converttohtmlmacro\xa\moodle@answertext@html\xa{\moodle@answertext}%
  \addto@xml[4]{\moodle@answers@xml}{  
   <text>\moodle@answertext@html</text>}%
  \ifx\moodle@feedback\@empty\relax\else
    \trim@spaces@in\moodle@feedback
    \xa\converttohtmlmacro\xa\moodle@feedback@html\xa{\moodle@feedback}%
    \addto@xml[4]{\moodle@answers@xml}{  <feedback 
     format="html"><text><![CDATA[<p>\moodle@feedback@html</p>]]></text></feedback>}%
  \fi
  \addto@xml[2]{\moodle@answers@xml}{</answer>}%
}%
\makeatother
```

With this patch, the following example questions gave satisfactory results (compilation with version `0.8` of `moodle`, Moodle LMS import, and question test on Moodle) :

```latex
\begin{shortanswer}{Q1}
Enter the string \texttt{"40\%"}.
\item[fraction=100,feedback={correct}] 40\%
\item[fraction=50,feedback={incomplete}] 40
\item[fraction=50,feedback={incomplete}] \%
\end{shortanswer}
\begin{cloze}{Q2}
\begin{shortanswer}
Enter the string \texttt{"40\%"}.
\item[fraction=100,feedback={correct}] 40\%
\item[fraction=50,feedback={incomplete}] 40
\item[fraction=50,feedback={incomplete}] \%
\end{shortanswer}
\end{cloze}
```

Problem 1. was recently [solved](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/commit/a0f458a7511fa387e04fc60216999c264ef5d30f#b671492e2e58a2af7c7ae716b570594a8625b688_4938_4957) in the development version of the package.
I opened an [issue](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/issues/88) for Problem 2. It should be resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine now. I submitted an edit where I swapped `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, and added the solution to problem 1.

Comment: Et merci mille fois pour cet outil, tellement utile par les temps de cours en distanciel.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Et de rien!

Comment: The bug still happen for package moodle version 0.9

Comment: @SayOL The example given above works for me with version `0.9`. Could you say more ? Provide a MWE ? You can reach me by email if necessary.

Comment: @mgk In my case the percentage is in math mode. I have tried to verify your solution and it works only in text mode `99\%` works, but `\( 99\% \)` does not work.

Comment: @SayOL Sorry. I still don't get it. First, in the context of answers of shortanswer questions, I don't understand why you would use math mode. Do you want the student to enter LaTeX code as an answer ? Second, I still cannot reproduce the problem. To provide more information on the problem you encounter (ideally with a MWE), you can open an issue on the [Gitlab instance](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle) or reach me by mail (see the title page of the package documentation).